# BizTalk WCF SendPort CDATA in response

Tags: wcf, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2010

For an integration with a 3th party webservice, I am receiving my "actual" data in a CDATA section.

```
<getDocumentsReqResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <getDocumentsReqResult>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsResult>
<rsCode>00</rsCode>
<rsMessage>...</rsMessage>
</wsResult>]]></getDocumentsReqResult>
</getDocumentsReqResponse>
```

So I was trying to use the Inbound path option on the send port. But When I try to do this, I get an empty message. Does this option work with CDATA?
I just entered the xpath (/*[local-name()='getDocumentsReqResponse' and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']/*[local-name()='getDocumentsReqResult' and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']) and put the Node encoding to string.
Or am I doing something wrong. I have used it in the past when I receive an HTML encoded string, but never with CDATA.

I will need an orchestration in the process anyway, so if that is the only option I will have to go for that.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a simple xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:getDocumentsReqResponse" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:getDocumentsReqResponse">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(s0:getDocumentsReqResult)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That also does the trick. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

/[local-name()='getDocumentsReqResponse']/[local-name()='getDocumentsReqResult']/text()

Technically in xPath, text() should return the CDATA content.  You can test it in any .Net app since it will behave the same.

Comment: I tried that already. No result :  Unable to find match for inbound body path expression. I tried with setting the encoding to string and xml.